# Plain text instead of checkboxes Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

In pinescript i add checkboxes with text to show information to the user.
But the option confuses sometimes, since an checkbox is an visible option.

Is there an way to just show text in the option box of the indicator without any crap checkbox or input field?

Currently using this to show text.
But that also shows in checkbox, which i dont want.

```
useRSI = input(false,title = "▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ USE RSI ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right there's no way to make such label in pine. But I'd rather use `type=string` with no other possible value, but empty string:

```
input(type=string, defval="", options=[""], title="▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ USE RSI ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬")
```

That's less frustrating for the users IMHO.